# xampp connect to external server database

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp

If anyone could help me that would be great.

I have installed xampp on a laptop and I also own a domain with its own database.

I want to be able to access the database from the site using my laptop. I have tried many different things to get it to work, it just wont.

I have accessed the firewall and set the port open, I have also used the flush-hosts function in the shell and that didn't work.

This is the error message I get:

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Host '213.235.57.38' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts' in C:\xampp\htdocs\see.php on line 11
>   cannot connect

That error message keeps appearing, To be honest, I have never tried to connect two databases together from two different servers, so I want to say that I'm sorry if I'm not getting this right, the code I have done so far is this:

```
<?php

$host = "(ip address)";
$username = "**********";
$password = "***********";
$db_name = "***********";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['User_ID'];
}

?>
```

That's the code I'm using and of course Im sure that I'm doing the whole connection wrong. But if anyone can help me get this sorted I would be so grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: Not all providers allow connections to the database server from another server.

Comment: Connecting to host called "$host" is probably not going to work.  Try dropping the quotation marks and just connecting to $host

Answer (score -1):

Now the next thing is to fix MySQL.

Once you find the `my.cnf/my.ini` file, open it up and find the line that has `[mysqld]`. Under that set of lines, add `skip-name-resolve`. This should fix the issue. Note that once you enable this, you might have some issues if you are trying to login on phpMyAdmin. See code for example.

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port= 3306
socket= "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir="C:/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir="C:/xampp/tmp" 
datadir="C:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file="mysql.pid"
skip-external-locking
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log_error="mysql_error.log"
skip-name-resolve
```

Reference:
http://blog.irvingduran.com/2013/02/how-to-access-xampp-from-external-address-http-and-mysql/

Comment: hey i have tired this and it hasn't worked just keeps giving me the same error i don't know why i just want to access my online database and transfer a few values from that database to the xampp database on my laptop